# Iphone Ipad Browser with Open in new tab xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, browser

I am trying to write App as Ipad browser. On my ipad, I only see this.But I need to have **"Open in new tab"**. I would like to know how to handle this problem. 
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a custom popover (as you said you are creating) a custom popover then, add another button, named what ever you want. And then on clicking on that button grab the link ank create `newWebView`, and load this link on `webView`.

Comment: No bro. I am not creating custom popover. It is auto with UIWebView.  But I see in safari on ipad and other browser application. They got "Open in new tab". I need to do like that bro